# Is there a way to hide input cells, that have no output?

Tags: cells, display

I can easily hide output cells, or hide the input cell if it produces output (just double click the side bracket for both).

> My Question is how can I hide input cells that have no output?

**Examples**

```
ToTeX[equation_] := 
  StringReplace[repRules][ToString[TeXForm[equation]]];
PrincipalMinorsStep1[mat_] := 
  Diagonal[Map[Reverse, Minors[mat, #], {0, 1}]] & /@ {1, 2} ;
PrincipalMinors[mat_] := PrincipalMinorsStep1[mat][[2, All]];
```

I would like to hide this block most of the time as I run it once upon initialization then never again.

Comment: Put it in a section. Put a section after it.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean?

Comment: Read [this](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/CreateAndWorkWithCells.html) about half-way down

Comment: Still confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your notebook make a section cell before your initialization code:

[image: blah]

Then double-click on the cell bracket of the first section group:

[image: blah2]

Now it's hidden.

Comment: That makes more sense, thank you.

Comment: How do you create subcells?

Comment: Same way as usual? If you mean section cells, you can read about that [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/KeyboardShortcutListing.html)

Comment: I have never created subcells before. Whenever I insert a new cell in never creates a subcell

Comment: @AzJ I'm not entirely sure what your problem is. It should be straightforward. But the documentation on this is more than sufficient if you just google "Mathematica make new section cell".